# Angular2 (CLI): separate common components and logic-components

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In angular 1.4 i was using ng6 boilerplate and it was generating an awesome structure, like:

```
app
  common
  components
  services


etc...
```

Now i'm trying to learn angular2 with typescript. I'm using Angular CLI.

And i wanna port some of structure from angular 1.4: i mean to separate, for example, select-component from customer-component etc.

And i created such structure:

[image]

components - is a module, customer is a module, list - is a component.

How in my app.component.html i can use list-component? Like:

```
<app-customer-list></app-customer-list>
```

I have troubles with importing modules & components.

I do it in a such way:

```
**app.module.ts**

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { ComponentsModule } from './components/components.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    ComponentsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

--

```
**components.module.ts**

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { CustomerModule } from './customer/customer.module';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CustomerModule
  ],
  declarations: []
})
export class ComponentsModule { }
```

--

```
**customer.module.ts**

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CustomerComponent } from './customer.component';
import { ListComponent } from './list/list.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ]
  declarations: [CustomerComponent, ListComponent]
})
export class CustomerModule { }
```

--

```
**list.component.ts**

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-customer-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.css']
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

What i do wrong? How can i correctly import them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are forgetting to export your components/modules in those modules that you are sharing with other modules:

```js
**customer.module.ts**

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CustomerComponent } from './customer.component';
import { ListComponent } from './list/list.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ]
  declarations: [CustomerComponent, ListComponent],
  exports: [CustomerComponent, ListComponent]
})
export class CustomerModule { }
```

```js
**components.module.ts**

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { CustomerModule } from './customer/customer.module';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CustomerModule
  ],
  exports: [CustomerModule]
  declarations: []
})
```

Comment: If you haven't already seen it, this FAQ about modules from the angular.io site is helpful:  https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html

Comment: will you be able to give me an advice?
for example i've checked this doc. "Provide the ContactService"

how can i use application-scoped providers without importing them with a huge import url (for example in contact module)

Comment: also... seems that i miss something in angular2 understanding... for example: if i wanna use NgbModule (bootstrap4), and i'm importing it in the list component: `import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'; ... imports: [NgbModule]` i get errors like: zone.js:388Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'ngb-panel' is not a known element:
but when i import this dependency everywhere, till i reach top - everything is fine